# Must I use -[UITableViewCell contentView] for uneditable cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm building something similar to the compose page of the native iPhone Mail app.

But, I'm putting two text fields on one row, and I want to separate them with a vertical divider (an additional view) that's the same color & weight as the horizontal cell separators.

Apple's docs say:

> If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

But, what if I know, like in this case, that my cell will never go into editing mode?

Also, the horizontal cell separators are subviews of the cell, not the cell's content view. So, I think it'd also make sense if I added the vertical divider to the cell, not the cell's content view.

Can I just add additional views to the cell itself, instead of its content view?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional views directly to the cell, but it's best practice to add them to the cell's content view. Even if you're cells never go into editing mode, this is what Apple and other developers that may be working on your code (or you in the future) are expecting. So, this will make it easier for them to work with your app.

For example, what if Apple hypothetically decided to put gutters on the left & right side of plain style table views in a future release of iOS? Then, they would probably inset the cell's content view but not the cell itself. That way, if you position your additional views relative to the content view, your app has a better chance of looking good and the additional views have a better chance of not getting clipped by Apple's hypothetical gutters. OK, I doubt Apple would do such a thing, but the point is that if you add your additional views to the cell's content view instead of the cell itself, you're code will be more robust.

For your specific case, I still recommend adding the vertical divider to the cell's content view because you can. You might even consider setting the `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and redrawing custom separators by adding a separator view to the bottom of each of your cells' content views. This way, you can be sure that the style of the vertical divider you add will always match that of the separators. Again, this will make your code more robust and protect you if Apple decides to change the style of their separators. Sure, you can use `cell.separatorColor`. And, you can guess the separator weight with `cell.frame.size.height - cell.contentView.frame.size.height`. But, such cleverness might get you in trouble.

As the Buddha admonishes Siddhartha, "Beware of too much cleverness!"